# How to print 1 to 100 without using loops, recursion, or goto statements in c programming?

Tags: c, algorithm

I found this solution from the internet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int n = 0;
void first() {
    void* x;
    printf("%d\n", ++n);
    if (n >= 100) {
        exit(0);
    }   
    *((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;
}
int main() {
    first();
    return 1;
}
```

Can someone explain me the meaning of the line `*((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;`?

Comment: That is actually *undefined behavior*. It uses knowledge of the stack layout of the compiler and the hardware platform, and modifies the functions return address so when `first` returns it returns to itself. Unless you have the exact CPU and compiler version that the program was designed for, you will most likely just get a crash. Which you might get anyway if the operating system has some kind of stack smashing protection. It will most definitely not work on a system with 64 bit pointers.

Comment: `***((char**) (&x + 4)) -= 5;**`  -- This line does not compile

Comment: `printf("1 2 3 4 5 ...")` - silly exercises require silly solutions.

Comment: `printf("1 to 100");` perhaps

Comment: The manipulation of the stack to return to yourself is a recursion. Even if you cannot see it on the first glance. So In my opinion this is not a valid answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I cannot answer because this question is closed, but you can do it using macro : `#define REP10(x) x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;` <br> `#define REP100(x) REP10(REP10(x))` then in your main `int i=0; REP100(printf("%d\n",++i))`

Answer (score 4):

The exercise makes absolutely no sense. That being said, it would seem your "hack" is trying to emulate the behavior of `setjmp/longjmp`, which stores/restores the state of the execution environment, such as the program counter.

```
// Silly code to solve artificial problems. Don't write programs like this.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

void silly_print (int max)
{
  jmp_buf jb;
  int n = setjmp(jb);
  printf("%d\n", ++n);
  if(n < max)
  {
    longjmp(jb, n);
  }
}

int main() 
{
  silly_print(100);
}
```

**Note:** `setjmp/longjmp` are considered dangerous because they could cause all manner of unintended side effects. They are also considered bad practice since they can be used for spaghetti programming, as done in the code above

Comment: So, it's a GOTO in disguise.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje A non local go-to to be exact.  It allows you to jump out of the current function directly to another.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Not really. `goto` translates to a non-conditional branch instruction. setjmp/longjmp translate to storing/restoring misc system variables. It is more like inline assembler in disguise.

Comment: @Lundin If i understand this correctly, GOTO affects the program counter, while longjmp affects the stack pointer, frame pointer and program counter.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje All conditional code results in branches and therefore affects the program counter... `goto` is of course no exception, it effects the program counter just like `if`, `for` or `while` do. It is not specified what sepjmp/longjmp affects, but it does indeed seem likely that it somehow stores the current state of the stack/data registers, as well as the program counter and maybe condition code registers. I must admit I have never bothered with disassembling setjmp/longjmp to have a look, as I don't intend to ever use those functions anyhow.